# resharper 'updating source files' does not stop (in Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

when I open up a project in Visual Studio (2015 in this case) a little progress 'thing' pops up at the lower right hand corner of Visual Studio.

[image]

AFAIK it is Resharper updating all the assemblies for its intellisense.
Normally it stops after a few seconds, or sometimes 20 seconds on large projects.

Now on this solution, suddenly, from this day, it won't stop!

So it starts small from the right site, grows to the left, then does it again, and again....  (longest time I've waited was 30 minutes).

In that time, the pc is slow and R# does not work in VS.

Already restarted VS and the pc, but that didn't help.

It only is for 1 solution, not for the other ones. And when i double click on it (which I did not know I could do before) it shows, very short, a little window what file it is working on and it shows a filename

[image]

(angular.js) which isn't even in this solution (to be complete, it is in another solution, but that is in a separate directory outside this solution.).

I realy don't have a clue....

EDIT

I've found this line in my visual studio .suo file for this solution:
C:\cv\Dev\Dev.2.1\Frontend\js\angular\directives\userAccessDirective.js
(the file is partly binary, so I can't just delete it I guess)
So I deleted the suo file, VS recreated it.... with the same filename!
(and the userAccessDirective.js uses the 'angular' term, I don't know if it has something to do with it, but it's weird that this reference is in the suo file for this solution)

EDIT 2

Removed the filename from the suo file, didn't make a difference

Comment: Are you using the resharper angularjs extension? If so, perhaps it's getting stuck in this file, and I'd suggest raising an issue in https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-angularjs. If you could include the file, or a link to it in a gist, that'd be great (or send it to me direct if you can't share publicly)

Comment: deleting the .suo file worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up re-installing Resharper which did the trick.

Comment: Similar problem, same solution (GUI blocked at least every 10 secs for 2 secs due to source update)

Answer (score 26):

I just had this happen in VS2017 and this worked:

1. ReSharper -> Options -> General -> Clear Cache
2. Tools -> Options -> ReSharper [Ultimate] -> Suspend
3. Tools -> Options -> ReSharper [Ultimate] -> Resume

Answer (score 7):

I've found that, if you're working with WPF (and hence have many XAML files), you get huge performance benefits by excluding XAML files from Resharper code inspection.

In VS, go to menu:
*Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Settings.*

Look at "Elements to skip' (you can only modify this with a project/solution loaded). On the right, add a file mask "*.xaml", and Save.

Comment: I filtered out *.tlh and *.tli and that did the trick for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper -> Options -> Intelisense -> General
Switch from ReSharper to Visual Studio

Comment: WOW! What a difference that made for a solution with 17 projects.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem with C++ files from standard library. 
After a long hard-working night ReSharper completed updating :)

Comment: I dond't think thas this is a answer which helps the questioner.

Comment: Author said: "(longest time I've waited was 30 minutes)". I'm suggested to wait longer, i.e. several hours.